# Hibernate many-to-one merge

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a class Person with id, name, and status . the status is a class Status with id, and status string
this is shortly the code generated by netbeans tool for hibernate

```
class Person{
   long id;
   String name;
   Status status;
   //getters and setters
}
class Status{
   long id;
   String status;
   List<Person> persons;
   //getters and setters
}
```

the problem is when I want to merge a person in the session I get the status null

Person p = getById(1L); // person name=XX; status=1

p.setName("YY");

session.merge(p); // here the status is get NULL 
not-null property references a null or transient value: model.Status

I know that hibernate load the person object when merging so why the status return as null;??

Answer (score 0):

In this case status is not null, but it's transient. You're trying to merge `Person` before merging the `Status` that the person contains. So you're trying to introduce in the hibernate context an entity that has a reference outside the context. The solution is either merging the status before merging the person or defining `CascadeType.MERGE`.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading only works when the many-to-one reference is using the other object's primary key. And also be avoid of creating your architecture on one2many relations.

Use like that in your person.hbm.xml file.

```
<set name="status" table="status" 
            inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="xxx.Status" />
 </set>
```

and status.hbm.xml should be like that;

```
 <many-to-one name="person" class="xxx.Person" fetch="select">
      <column name="id" not-null="true" />
 </many-to-one>
```

i hope it helps.